# iOS RangeOfString NSRegularExpressionSearch

Tags: regex, nsrange

i have a small problem, i am using one code snippet to remove html code from iOS string:

```
while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
        s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
```

and now i need to remove some blocks, like . Why this snippet is not working:

```
while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<style[^>]+style>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
    s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info Unless you give more assumptions about the input, it is better to use parser to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<style[^>]+>[^>]+</style>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound) {
   s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
```

}